# Защита Python-keras от просмотра исходников

Tags: c++, python, нейронные-сети, защита

Всех приветствую. У меня появился очень странный вопрос, но:

Как можно защитить python скрипт от просмотра исходников? (взлома)

Суть в чем:

Скрипт - обычная нейросеть, написанная на python, библиотеке Keras.

Она просто распознает картинки.

Но картинки она распознает 1 раз в 50 миллисекунд, грубо говоря, в реальном времени.

Из-за этого скрипт должен быть на компьютере пользователя, при этом, он должен прожить хотя бы месяц-два без взлома программы.

Думал запускать keras модель на C++, но так и не нашел нормальную библиотеку, которая смогла бы мне помочь.

Также думал поставить скрипт на какой-нибудь сервер, но скрипт съедает примерно 20% от моего неслабого процессора.

Как быть?

Comment: Плохо искали: [Как я Keras на C++ запускал](https://habr.com/ru/post/438398/)

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/308002/

Comment: [Cython](https://cython.org/)?